# Get date from input form within PHP

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker

I'm trying to retrieve a date from a date input form and I just can't get it to work properly. The code I'm using now only returns an error and this date: 1970-01-01. That is not correct and I would like to know how I can approach this. This will be used later to query a database table. I want the date to be basically just a string with this format: "yyyy-mm-dd"

Code:

**HTML**

```
<form name="DateFilter" method="POST">
From:
<input type="date" name="dateFrom" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
<br/>
To:
<input type="date" name="dateTo" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']));
echo $new_date;
```

**~~~ EDIT ~~~**

*Fixed Solution for anyone wondering how it's done:*

**HTML**

```
<form name="Filter" method="POST">
    From:
    <input type="date" name="dateFrom" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
    <br/>
    To:
    <input type="date" name="dateTo" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']));
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: what does `$_POST['dateFrom']` return?

Comment: Works fine for me, can't reproduce it. Are you sure you submitted your form?

Comment: your form is missing `action`

Comment: @Lal if a form is missing `action`, it just sends the post request to the current page.

Comment: $_POST['dateFrom'] returns an error and 1970-01-01

Comment: I am checking if (isset($_POST)) inside the current page so I guess I don't need action, right?

Comment: I changed the input to be in my other form tag and now it works fine. Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: Thank you everyone who contributed. Silly mistake on my part

Comment: You should still validate the dates.  You may be able to fix some.

Comment: Please don't put answers in question posts. Question posts are for questions, and answer posts are for answers.

Answer (score 7):

Validate the INPUT.

```
$time = strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']);
if ($time) {
  $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
  echo $new_date;
} else {
   echo 'Invalid Date: ' . $_POST['dateFrom'];
  // fix it.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['birthdate'])) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($_POST['birthdate']); 
    $date=date('d',$timestamp);
    $month=date('m',$timestamp);
    $year=date('Y',$timestamp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Send post method input type date data in this script. and echo anything you want, Like a date, month, year !! you will get this easily