# Multiple input type data on one page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having hard time figuring how I can pass from multiple input forms with date type directly to mysql, when I'm trying to print_r or echo what I have here the date is always 01-01-1970. I saw a similar problem here: [stacklink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243775/get-date-from-input-form-within-php) but I'm not sure how he get it working? What am I missing?

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">      
    <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4">
        <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Data przybycia:</strong></h3>
        <hr />
      <input class="form-control" name="dateFrom" value="<?php
      echo $dateNextDay; ?>" type="date" min="<?php
      echo $dateNextDay; ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Data odjazdu:</strong></h3>
        <hr />
      <input class="form-control" name="dateTo" value="<?php
      echo $dateNextDayNextDay; ?>" type="date" min="<?php
      echo $dateNextDayNextDay; ?>">
      </div>
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$ldateFrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($POST_['dateFrom']));

$ldateTo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($POST_['dateFrom']));
```

Comment: what is this $POST_['dateFrom'] ?     you have to access the post variable like this $_POST['dateFrom']

Comment: $dateNextDay; where its come from ?

Comment: that's irrelevant, all is working now ;) You can post your answer so I can accept it if you want :)! Have a good day sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the `$_POST` value like this instead of `$POST_['dateFrom']`

```
$ldateFrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']));
```