# Form Date Input to Database with php and mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

So I am trying to create a form that uploads an image, description and Date into a database. Everything is working but the date stays at 0000-00-00 no matter what I've tried, any ideas? I was following a tutorial for most of it, but it doesn't add the date and I would like to, because later I want to be able to call up these entries by the date they are submitted as.

```
    <?php require('check.php');
    require_once('settings.php'); 
    include('header.php');
      // Create database connection
      $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "-----", "-----", "----");

      // Initialize message variable
      $msg = "";

      // If upload button is clicked ...
      if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        // Get image name
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        // Get text
        $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);
        // Get Date
        $sermon_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['sermon_date']);
        // image file directory
        $target = "images/sermons/".basename($image);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text, sermon_date) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text', '$sermon_date')";
        // execute query
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
        }else{
            $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
      }
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
      $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
    ?>

    <h1>Update Sermon Series</h1>
      <form method="POST" action="success.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
        Sermon Graphic <br />
          <input type="file" name="image"><br /><br />

          <textarea 
            id="text" 
            cols="40" 
            rows="4" 
            name="image_text" 
            placeholder="Describe Sermon"></textarea><br />
    Beginning Date of Sermon:<br />
    <input type="date" name="sermon_date">
            <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is where I create the table

```
    $connect = new MySQLi($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE images (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
image VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
image_text LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
sermon_date DATE NOT NULL
)";

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table:" . $connect ->error;
}
```

Comment: What is the field type of `sermon_date` in your db table? and have you var_dump the posted value from html form to see what is getting posted to the script?

Comment: This question and answer may help. See the "edit" part of the question to see what the OP had done to fix the problem (essentially the date had to be formatted to Y-m-d before insert): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243775/get-date-from-input-form-within-php

Comment: You should provide the `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Comment: I'm looking over what RToyo linkedf, I also edited my post to have what I used to create my tables. Field type is date in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date needs to be saved to the database in format `YYYY-MM-DD`, which the date field in your HTML should be doing already.

If your input is not sending the date in this format (for whatever reason), you can convert it to this format using PHP. The below code takes the posted date and converts it to the above format (in PHP, this translates to `Y-m-d`).

```
// add this above the insert query
$sermon_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sermon_date));
```

Note that the `strtotime` may not work if the date you're accepting is not of a standard format that PHP can detect.